# Unable to move sourceMap(.map) files to separate folders in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.5

I'm using Sublime Typescript Plugin to transpile Typescript files.

**Project folder**

[image]

I've done all the setup for a sample project with help of tsconfig.json(using Typescript 1.5V). Below is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration":false,
        "mapRoot":"mapFiles",  
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "js",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "sourceRoot": "mapFiles",
        "target":"es3",
        "watch":true,
        "rootDir":""
    }

}
```

To move all the sourceMap files into other folder(mapFiles) folder rather than keeping in all the files(.js and .map files) in same folder, I've added below config into tsconfig.json

```
"mapRoot":"mapFiles", 
"sourceMap": true,
"sourceRoot": "mapFiles",
```

After done the build, Script files are generated successfully along with sourceMappingURL comments. Below is the out of **main.ts** file.

```
var x = "will work";
//# sourceMappingURL=E:/type/projects/Examples/ex1/mapFiles/main.js.map
```

But main.js.map file is not moved the respective folder(mapFiles). It is in same folder where the js file is generated.

```
Below is my understanding about .maps files:

1. Map files have the details about the respective .ts files with location of it.

2. it is used to track down .ts files easily.
```

Please let me know how to move sourceMap files to other folders on run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something similar to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders). Take a look there and you will certainly be able to decide what approach fits your wishes.

I don't see a problem in leaving them both on the same folder whereas **`*.js.map`** and **`*.js`** won't even be pushed to your repo, just `.gitignore` them. I use IntelliJ with the Typescript plugin, which already helps to keep my eyes from drying out.
[Here's how it looks like with my setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtex9.png)

If there is a reason to separate them and I am not aware of it, then you can write a task that separates them. So keep  `"mapRoot":"mapFiles", "outDir": "js",` in your tsconfig.json and add a script in package.json to move them.