# Separate Angular2 TypeScript files and JavaScript files into different folders, maybe 'dist‘

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am using the [5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) from angular.io website, which contain a file structure like this:

```
angular2-quickstart
 app
   app.component.ts
   boot.ts
 index.html
 license.md
 package.json
 tsconfig.json
```

the tsconfig.json is a code block like this ：

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Also the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

I change the sourceMap from true to false, so in the code editor, the map file is not generated again, but the js file still get generated.

I want to work on only ts file and don't want to get a brunch of js and js.map file, what should I do to put all my ts files in my regular develop floder like app folder and all the js and js.map files into a folder called dist?

A good example of this might be [angular2-webpack-quickstart](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). But I didn't figure out how they do that?

Any advice how to do that, of course not manually.

Thanks,

Comment: you have to compile the typescript to js  thats how the browser reads it  take a look at                     format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
in your index.html

Comment: angular2-webpack-starter is very much up to date, it is currently on beta 1.  Suggest you get more familiar with git (particularly git pull).

Comment: @TimMcNamara I grab the angular2-webpack-starter and start develop like one month ago, but it's set to a different remote private github url already, so in this case, how should I get up to date with angular2-webpack-starter, which part should I update? Thanks.

Comment: You could just replace your package.json with the current one from here [link](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/package.json) wipe out `node_modules` and `npm install` to bring everything up to date

Comment: Do [what raheel shan said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37164273/5155810). EXCEPT in **system.config.js** it should be 'app': 'dist/app' // instead of just 'dist'

Comment: There is an extension for VS Code see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41256608/234110 for more details

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Probably late but here is a two-step solution.

### Step 1

Change **system.config.js** by updating `'app'` to `'dist/app'`:

```
var  map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist/app',
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Now it will look like this:

```
var  map = {
    'app':                        'dist/app', // 'dist/app',
    .
    .
    .
};
```

### Step 2

Create the **dist** folder. 
Edit **tsconfig.json** and add:

```
"outDir": "dist"
```

The resulting `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    .
    .
    .
    .

    "outDir": "dist" // Pay attention here
  },
  "exclude": [
    .
    .
    .
  ]
}
```

Run `npm start` and you should see all the compiled `.js` and `.map.js` files in the **dist** folder.

**Note**: Go through other answers. They are quite useful and informative too.

Comment: I tried this, it works. Unfortunately, my html/css files is not present in the dist folder. How to do in order to copy all html/css in dist folder ? thanks

Comment: I tried this and after a while an app directory gets created in my dist folder.

Comment: How do you deal with the required node_modules like @angular ?  Do you have to copy all of these into the dist directory with every build?

Comment: To future readers: the question `html/css files is not present in the dist folder` have answers below...

Comment: The "dist" folder doesn't need to be committed, right? I have it excluded from my Visual Studio project and want to be sure that is right.

Comment: @Brett surely its up to you.

Comment: In my case, its not generating all the files inside the "app" folder. It's generating in root. Ideally the generation path should be dist > app > *.js files but it's generating dist > *.js files and hence giving 404

Comment: per ```html/css files not present in the build folder``` Check my answer for a clean solution that doesn't involve moving things around .. if you definitely need that you can set up gulp, otherwise defaults are plenty for Angular 2 and CommonJs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40694657/986160

Answer (score 21):

My solution is a bit different from the above.
I was starting from the Angular2 Quickstart seed defined here: https://github.com/angular/quickstart#create-a-new-project-based-on-the-quickstart

And then only changed the following:

- Added `"outDir": "../dist"` to `tsconfig.json`
- Changed the `baseDir` attribute inside `bs-config.json` to `"baseDir": ["dist", "src"]`

Then `npm run start` works as before (even html/css and other files without any copying), but compiled `.js` and `.map` files are built into `dist/app` and won't pollute your `src/app` directory.

Please note that I haven't tested how this affects testing yet.

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest solution

Comment: this is the best!

Comment: It works! But, does anyone have problems like me, debugging the application with Chrome DevTools? I get the .ts files in blank.

Comment: fantastic solutions. Really easy and very clean!

Answer (score 17):

I may be also late but I did this.

First do [what raheel shan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37164273/6322165).

Then create the **dist** folder. 
After creating the folder go to the file `tsconfig.json` and add this:

```
"outDir": "dist"
```

The resulting `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

If you now run `npm start` and save a file you should see all the compiled `.js` and `.map.js` in the **dist** folder.

Answer (score 8):

Thanx raheel shan, your answer gave a head start,

As @Adavo rightly asked above in comments

> Unfortunately, my html/css files is not
>   present in the dist folder. How to do in order to copy all html/css in
>   dist folder ?

The answer to this question is 
* provide full path to HTML/CSS File using '/' (from root Directory) in all the .ts Files and mainly in "templateURL" property of @Component

after a lot of time - I got it figured it out - without using Gulp :) Yipppeee

Comment: Is there a solution anyone can suggest for doing this without having to provide the full path?  ...preferably a simple solution that doesn't require a complete overhaul of an otherwise working build system.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be possible, you can try angular-cli for better code organizing but this full path to html is require in that as well

Comment: I figured out a way!  See the answer I provided below.  I guess it isn't perfect, but solves the problem using just npm scripts, no grunt/gulp/angular-cli.  Not that I have anything against those solutions but I just wasn't into figuring them out right now!

Comment: Check my answer it is a pretty clean change with manipulating model.id a bit http://stackoverflow.com/a/40694657/986160

Answer (score 7):

So, to solve this:

> Unfortunately, my html/css files is not present in the dist folder. How to do in order to copy all html/css in dist folder ?

Do the steps in both @raheel shan and @Lirianer's answers.  ...then you can finish it off with this.

I have solved this for my purposes using npm scripts.  The scripts section in my package.json file is below.  The solution is to run `onchnage` (an npm package - `npm install --save onchange`) concurrently with `tsc` and the server.  Then use rsync to copy the assets you want to move:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run watchassets\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "movesssets": "rsync -a --include='*.css' --include='*.html' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ./app/ ./build/",
    "watchassets": "onchange 'app/**/*.css' 'app/**/*.html' -e 'build/*' -v -- rsync -a --include='*.css' --include='*.html' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ./app/ ./build/"
}
```

For those of you on Windows you can get `rsync` via `Cygwin` or with packaged solutions such as [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync).

Comment: ...although I'm using a `build` folder and not a `dist` folder, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but you really need to add where `onchange` is coming from. Also, you should post a note that this installment only works for unix-like shells. Maybe that's not so much of an issue for most people, but I lately came across a lot of devs (forced to be) using windows.

Comment: OK - I have added an explanation of where `onchange` is coming from and information on how to get `rsync` for Windows.  Let me know if this addresses your issues.

Answer (score 7):

> Unfortunately, my html/css files is not present in the dist folder. How to do in order to copy all html/css in dist folder ?

Relative paths in Angular 2 are not that straightforward because the framework wants to be flexible with how you load your files (CommonJs, SystemJs, .. etc)
according to [Component-Relative Paths in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html) article.

As the article explains `module.id` when used with CommonJs (check your tsconfig.json) contains the absolute root of the module and it can be used to construct a relative path.

So a better alternative could be to leave the css/html files with the ts files and configure your component like below, assuming you just have your build files in a separate folder called **dist**.. This way your css and html files will be loaded with no problem using relative paths by converting the derived build path to the source one that contains them - essentially removing `/dist/` or renaming it to `/src/` ;)

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/"),
   templateUrl: 'relative-path-to-template/component.html',
...
});
```

if you have separate  folders for source and build you can do this instead:

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/src/"),
   templateUrl: 'relative-path-to-template/component.html',
...
});
```

Comment: although this is a good work around...still the major problem of fetching all our project files from our project depends on two different folders...is there any way to deploy our code from a single folder to the browser. Thanks in advance

Comment: even in the case of node_modules you were running a build script. Each of the node_modules usually has the source js and the min.js files. So I don't see why it is a problem to deploy your source code and then run your build script to download node_module dependencies and compile the typescript which will create the dist folder. Obviously you can configure webpack or similar processes to do the bundling in a different way.

Answer (score 5):

I tried **@WillyC**'s suggestion and worked like a charm, just note that you'll have to add the `onchange` dependency to your `package.json` file. I added a little just a little extra scripts to have a clean setup upon first run and also to remove leftover html/css files (it'd be nice if same could be done for TSC)

Anyway, here is a section of my `package.json` file

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run cleandist && npm run moveassets && tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" \"npm run watchassets\" ",
    ...
    "cleandist": "rm -rf dist/*",
    "moveassets": "rsync -a --include='*.css' --include='*.html' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ./app/ ./dist/",
    "watchassets": "onchange 'app/**/*.css' 'app/**/*.html' -e 'dist/*' -v -- rsync -a --include='*.css' --include='*.html' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --delete ./app/ ./dist/"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "onchange":"^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

For the `rsync` delete, notice the `--delete` flag on the `rsync` command of the `watchassets` script

Answer (score 3):

### Angular2 TypeScript files and JavaScript files into different folder

Here is my config for Angular 2 the latest version V2.1.1, and it work very well!

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "./app/dist"
    }
}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      // app: 'app/dist',  &&  main: './dist/main.js',
      // Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/dist/dist/main.js(…)
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        // index.html import path
        // Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/dist/main.js(…)
        // app: 'app/dist',  &&  main: './main.js',
        main: './dist/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

[image]

Comment: [more details](https://github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/AngularJS/tree/patch-5/Tutorials)

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed this line to: `main: './dist/app/main.js',`

Comment: This post and comment + http://stackoverflow.com/a/40694657/5393271 do the job. If u have different folders in app with services or components like app/components/mycomp.components.ts; app/services/myservice.service.ts it will automatically create those folders in dist after executing npm start(building)

Comment: you also can do this: in `system.js.config` at - `map{app:"dist",..}` then in `packages{app{main:"app/main.js"}}`} and in `tsconfig.json` -  `"outDir": "dist"` + [html/css source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40694657/5393271)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Nagyl, I developed my own way and I believe it's worth to share:

1) Install cpx

```
npm install cpx
```

2) Update bs-config.json and change baseDir from "src" to "dist"

```
"baseDir":"dist"
```

3) Update tsconfig.json and add outDir to end of compilerOptions:

```
"outDir": "../dist"
```

4) Update package.json:
4.1) add a new command to end of scripts:

```
"cpx": "cpx \"src/**/*.{html,css,js,png,jpg}\" dist --watch"
```

4.2) modify "start" line to include "cpx" command:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run cpx\" \"npm run serve\"",
```

[image: Step 2 modification]

[image: Step 3 modification]

[image: Step 4 modification]

Answer (score 2):

You can transpile `.ts` files in the browser, just like [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) is doing in their angular 2 ts template.

Just launch editor, select new, then AngularJS, and 2.0.x (TS) option(on the very bottom). But the whole point of using webpack(or any other bundling tool) is to transpile files locally.

Answer (score 2):

I tried few of the above mentioned options and finally, this is what I settled on: [Peep](https://github.com/natewallace/peep) - an **extension** for `Visual Studio Code`.

How to install:

- View -> Extensions
- Peep
- Install
- Reload
- View -> Command Pallet
- Peep None
- modify .vscode/settings.json as required (mine shown below)

-

```
{
  "typescript.check.workspaceVersion": false,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/*.js": true,
    "**/*.js.map": true,
    "node_modules/": true,
    "dist/": true,
    "lib/": true
  }
}
```

**01/25/2017 - updates:** *angular-cli* out of the box, takes care of this. and installation works and now.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solutions listed here. They are good, but not ideal for me. I want a simple solution. I don't want to hard-code the path information in all my component files. I don't want to install more npm packages to take care of this.

So I come up an easiest alternative. It's not a direct answer to this question, but it works very well for me.

I just tweak my workspace settings so that the `js` files under `/app` don't show. They are still there. They are just hidden from my workspace. To me, that's enough.

I'm using Sublime Text, so here is what I have for my project settings:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["app/*.js"]
```

I'm sure many other editors have similar functions.

**UPDATE:**

Just use Angular CLI. Everything is taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 4 with files from quickstart, all I had to do was the following (a mix of the previously stated answers but slightly different values) :

- In tsconfig.json (add) : `"outDir": "../dist"`
- In bs-config.json (change) : `"baseDir": ["dist", "src"],`
- In bs-config.e2e.json (change) : `"baseDir": ["dist", "src"],`

No change to systemjs.config.js.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestion of @raheel & it worked for me. I have modified the structure according to my needs.

I am using the following structure

[image: I am using the following structure]

To get this  I have modified only two files 1. systemjs.config.js and 2.tsconfig.json

In systemjs.config.js I changed to

`map: {
      // previously it was app: 'app',
      app: 'app/js',
...`

[image: systemjs.config.js]

and in tsconfig.json I have to add `"outDir": "app/js"`

[image: tsconfig.json]

Comment: I am doing same thing whatever you maintion but after npm start .js file not create in app/js folder

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Angular 2.4. I needed an extra step to make it work. This was update systemJs reference to main.js file in index.html
it's, from:

> System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);
>   });

to:

> System.import('dist/main.js').catch(function(err){
>   console.error(err); });

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of what raheel shan said.
I had to make additional change in index.html to reflect to import correct javascript file now.

Here is summary from my side.

**tsconfig.json**

Before

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

After:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [ 
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

Before:

```
'app': 'app',
```

After:

```
'app': 'dist/app', //'app
```

**index.html**

Before:

```
System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

After:

```
System.import('dist/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```