# How can separate js files and ts files automatically in angular after npm start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Can I get this result modifying tsconfig.json or package.json?

I want this structure:

```
angular2-quickstart
  app
    ts
      app.component.ts
      main.ts
    js
      app.component.js
      app.component.js.map
      main.js
      main.js.map
index.html
license.md
```

no this:

```
angular2-quickstart
  app
    app.component.ts
    main.ts
    app.component.js
    app.component.js.map
    main.js
    main.js.map
index.html
license.md
```

Comment: Did you consider to use Gulp instead of npm build? There is great article about this topic at http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/24/creating-an-angular-2-build.html

Comment: Same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders/42790972#42790972

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can tell the TypeScript compiler to output `.js` files to a different directory using the `outDir` option in `tsconfig.json`, and I'd recommend setting the `rootDir` too so as to avoid unpleasant surprises in the future:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "app/js",
    "rootDir": "app/ts",
  }
}
```

Don't forget to adjust paths in `index.html`.

Comment: It's not working in  version Angular 2 - rc7. Please Update

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate out .js and .ts files in angular2, you have to follow only two steps:-

1) Add `"outDir":"<folder name where you want to put your js Files>"` within compilerOptions  object in `tsconfig.json` file.

2) Map your folder in `systemjs.config.js` i.e modify the map object like

```
 map:{
     app:<Folder-Name which you have specified in outDir>
     ----
     ----

 }
```