# Angular 2 + Typescript compiler copy html and css files

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular2 I would have

```
"outDir": "dist/app"
```

in tsconfig.json. As a result the transpiled .js and .map files are generated in /dist/app/ folder and/or its sub folders. That works all fine.

In my components.ts files I also used referenced html and css like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  templateUrl: 'app/appshell/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/appshell/app.component.css'],
  ......
}
```

Is there any way to make compiler to also copy the referenced html and css files for the whole project?
If yes, how would I configure my tsconfig.json?

I looked into the compiler options here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html but didn't find anything about copying html/css files.

**Update:**
My folder structure is like this

```
Root
  |--app       // for ts
  |--dist/app  // for js
```

tsconfig.json

```
"outDir": "dist/app"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "TestApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "html": "find ./app -name '*.html' -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./dist \\;",
    ......
}
```

It doesn't copy html files. There is no error though.

**Update again:**

For those who are on Linux OS, Bernardo's solution is a working one.
For those who are on Windows OS, the following should work.

```
  "scripts": {
    "html": "XCOPY /S /y .\\app\\*.html .\\dist\\app" }
```

Comment: Just to expose you to ecosystems that you might not have considered, its easy to package everthing as JS today with TypeScript+React+FreeStyle (https://medium.com/@basarat/css-modules-are-not-the-solution-1235696863d6) 

Comment: `xcopy` is deprecated. An good alternative would be a `"static": "robocopy app dist\\app *.html *.css /e /purge"` and a `"build": "npm run start && npm run static"`. So you could build the whole app in one step or separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, the TypeScript compiler is just for *.ts file.

You have to copy other files like *.html and *.css using a copy method like  `cp` shell command inside a npm script or [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) for example.

Example using npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "html": "find ./app -name '*.html' -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./dist \\;"
}
```

Just run `npm run html` in the shell.

Example using grunt:

```
copy: {
      html: {
          src: ['**/*.html'],
          dest: 'dist',
          cwd: 'app',
          expand: true,
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what is the syntax for npm recursive cp script? `"html":   "cp -R app/*.html dist/app/",` does not work.

Comment: @Shawn I've updated the npm html script. Now it'll copy all the *.html files keeping the directory structure. Please, test it.

Comment: Bernardo, I tried your code. It didn't copy the html files. I updated my post to let you see what I did. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the update, now I see what's wrong. You must copy to the `./dist` folder instead of `./dist/app` folder. The `--parents` already clone the folder structure. Use exactly the command that I put above. Also, you must have to ensure that the `./dist` folder exist before you copy the html files. So, before running `npm run html`, the `dist` folder must exist.

Comment: Bernardo, dist folder exists and I did exactly `"html": "find ./app -name '*.html' -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./dist \\;"`. But it still didn't do it.

Comment: What are the errors in the console? The package.json you post show you're copying to dist/app.

Comment: There is no error. I updated my post. the `find` command is a OS command or npm command?

Comment: @Shawn you're running your whole build process, not the command we're discussing. Please, run just `npm run html` to copy the html files.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I ran `npm run html` and it gave the error `File not found - '*.html'`. Do I need to add a recursive option?

Comment: I think `find` command is a lunix command. If yes, then I would have to find similar things for Windows.

Comment: I tried this command and its giving the error find: missing argument to `-exec'. "mycommand": "find ./src/utils/curl -name \"*.exe\" -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./lib \\;" and then when I run mycommand, i get the above error

Comment: is there an tsconfig command that will run this script on change detected?

Answer (score 56):

For an OS independent solution, use [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles)

```
npm install copyfiles --save-dev
```

Then add a script to package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "html": "copyfiles -u 1 app/**/*.html app/**/*.css dist/"
}
```

Now npm run html should copy all css and html files from the app/ folder to dist/app/

**EDIT:** I'd like to amend my answer to point out [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/). This command line tooling utility is supported by the angular team and makes bundling a breeze (ng build --prod), among other things.

Comment: I had to add -u 1 to not include the main folder (src) as the destination folder name was different (dist)

Comment: @AlejandroB.Thanks for pointing that out. I added it to my answer.

Comment: we are all here to help

Answer (score 4):

This approach is provided by Microsoft:-
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter
Check out the file "copyStaticAssets".
None of the solutions above worked for me, so I hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 3):

From the Bernardo's answer  I changed this

```
 "html": "find ./app -name '.html' -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./dist \\;"
```

for this 

```
"html": "cd app && tsc && find . \( -name '.html' -or -name '*.css' \) -type f -exec cp --parents {} ../dist \\;"
```

 and is working good. Compile and copy html and css files in one instruction I also added this

```
"clean": "rm -rf dist"
```

in order to remove the whole directory **dist**. Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

@yesh kumar, Thanks for sharing the link. Here the steps I did

- Install[shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)
- Add static assets to `copyStaticAssets.ts` file

```js
import * as shell from "shelljs";

shell.cp("-R", "lib/certs", "dist/");
```

- Configure `ts-node copyStaticAssets.ts` in `package.json` script section

  ```js
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && npm run copy-static-assets",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start",
    "copy-static-assets": "ts-node copyStaticAssets.ts"
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative from my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694657/986160
could be to leave your css and html with the ts files. Then you can use module.id which will have the path pointing to the js of the component and after converting it accordingly you can essentially use relative paths :)

For your case I think something like that will work:

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/"),
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative using `nodemon` from my answer here: [Watch template files and copy them to dist/ folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159379/watch-template-files-and-copy-them-to-dist-folder/51034324#51034324) could be configured using `package.json` to put your css and html files with a simple copy commnad of your host OS.

But, in this days, you have `Webpack` in the Angular 4/5 ecosystem.