# Angular2 : Html and css files are not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to separate the html and css files on the basis of the respective components.Here is the folder structure

[image]

In the above image, app is working as source containing components and respective html and css files and respective js files are generating in 'build' folder. To copy css and html files, I found out to use following script in pacakge.json from here : [Angular 2 + Typescript compiler copy html and css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708200/angular-2-typescript-compiler-copy-html-and-css-files):

```
"html": "find ./app -name '*.html' -type f -exec cp --parents {} ./dist \\;"
```

and running following command:

```
npm run html
```

But it is not copying the html files to 'build'. Any suggestion

Comment: You might want to try Webpack, especially as part of [NG-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). We had to deal with similar issues before with SystemJS, but once we spent an hour to switch to NG-CLI, these sorts of issues and more are handled now automatically. Our build size decreased also substantially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708200/angular-2-typescript-compiler-copy-html-and-css-files), I tried following and it works

```
"html": "XCOPY /S /y .\\src\\app\\*.html .\\src\\build\\app",
"css": "XCOPY /S /y .\\src\\app\\*.css .\\src\\build\\app"
```