# Watch template files and copy them to dist/ folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript on my project and I can successfully watch + compile .ts files and output them to `dist` folder.

here is the `scripts` part of my `package.json`

```
"start": "npm run build && npm run watch",
    "build": "npm run build-ts && npm run tslint",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "watch": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Typescript,Node\" -c \"cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json"
```

The problem is I want to use js templating engine `(nunjucks)` and I need to watch the view files inside the `views` folder and move them to the `dist` folder.

- Is there a way by just using `npm scripts` or `nodejs`?
- Or do I need to use other tools like `gulp` or `webpack`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the "same" request to for a CRUD graphql back-end server, but don't want to use `gulp` or `webpack` just to keep it simple.

I see that you use `nodemon` like me. Then, according the docs at https://github.com/remy/nodemon, it can be used it to monitor changes of any kind of file other than the default `js`. More over, `nodemon` can monitor the status of other transactional server other than `node`.

The first task is detecting the changes of wanted files: in my case I want copy the  `*.gql` files in my `src/schema` folder to `build/schema` folder. For that, you can use the `ext` for the kind of files, and `watch` option for the source folder to explore.

The second one task is matter of copying the files. Naturally, you can use the copy command of your host OS. In my case I use the DOS `xcopy` command of the Windows shell (or `cp` in Unix like OS). `nodemon` has an "event-hook" with the `event` option, that can execute a command line when an event occurs. Just we need the `restart` event of the node server when the changes are detected for `nodemon`.

You can use the command line options, or a global config file, or in you local `package.json` project config file. I show up the last one using `nodemonConfig` section of `package.json`:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "watch": [
     "./src/schema",
     "./build"
  ],
  "ext": "js,gql",
  "events": {
     "restart": "xcopy .\\src\\schema\\*.gql .\\build\\schema /Y /O /R /F /I /V /E"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to add an `"ignore"` configuration for the destination of the `graphql` files to stop an infinite restart: `"ignore": ["./dist/schemas/**/*.graphql"]`

Answer (score 4):

[copy-and-watch](https://github.com/zont/copy-and-watch) does just that:

I use this code to copy html files during development:

```
"copy_html": "yarn copy-and-watch src/mail_templates/* prod/mail_templates --watch --clean",
```

Answer (score 3):

Ozkr's answer is great, I just want to add what worked for me, I had to change it a bit as nodemon was running into an infinite restart otherwise:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
"watch": [
   "./views",
   "./public"
],
"ext": "hjs,js",
"events": {
   "restart": "cp -r views dist \n cp -r public dist"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**OZk's** answer is great. in my case i only had to add the `nodemonConfig` in `package.json` and watch `src` folder nothing else. it worked like a charm

```bash
 "nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": [
      "./src"
    ],
    "ext": "ts,graphql,js"
  },
```