# Resource file missing in TypeScript package

Tags: json, node.js, typescript, lerna

I have a Lerna project containing two Typescript packages A and B. The `tsconfig.json` for both packages is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "test"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**",
    "packages/*/node_modules/**",
    "examples/*/node_modules/**",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Package A contains the following code:

```
const data = require('./myData.json');
```

Package B depends on package A. Inside package B a call is made to a function exported by package A, and so the above code is loaded. However, I get `Error: Cannot find module './myData.json'` in this context. Now, looking inside compiler output directory for package A I do not see the JSON file. Indeed, looking inside package B's `node_modules` directory at package A I do not see the file there either.

Why might the JSON file missing from the published package? Is there anything special that needs to be done to include resource files (JSON, plaintext) in the Typescript package?

Comment: As far as I know, `tsc` has no option to copy resource files; you'll need to use a separate tool.  I'll leave the question unanswered to encourage people to suggest their favorite tools/approaches.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize this. This link seems relevant to your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708200/angular-2-typescript-compiler-copy-html-and-css-files