# Angular2 templateurl fails after changing the output directory for js files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have edited the system.js.config.js to output the js files to a different folder with

```
    map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  'app':'dist/app',
```

and also changed the tsconfig.json to

```
     "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"outDir": "dist"
```

}

Now with the above the js files are outputted in the dist folder keeping the app folder clean with only the typescript files

Now the js files are correctly loaded but when i use templateurl in the component template it always refers to the dist folder that is

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'hero-form',
  templateUrl: 'hero-form.component.html'
})
```

The above is resolved by having to copy the hero-form.component.html to the dist folder
Is there another workaround without having to copy the html to dist folder since this means there will always be code repetition

Comment: You may want to look at the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders