# Delete js files from dist folder when deleting ts files angular 2 project

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm

I followed the answer here

[Separate Angular2 TypeScript files and JavaScript files into different folders, maybe 'dist‘](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders/40694657#40694657) 
in order to separate my files into `app` and `dist` folders. The interesting thing is that when I create a new `.ts` file somewhere in the `app` folder ir creates a `.js` and `.js.map` files automatically in the `dist` folder, but when I delete a `.ts` file from the `app` folder the corresponfing `.js` and `.js.map` files from the `dist` folder are not deleted. Why is that and how can I fix it ?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "primeng": "1.0.0",
    "querystring": "0.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.1.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "outDir" : "dist"
  },
   "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'dist',
      // our app modules
      'domain' : 'app/domain',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'primeng':                   'npm:primeng'            
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'                
      },
      // for our app modules
      domain : {
        main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      // other libraries
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      primeng: {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      }      
    }
  });
})(this);
```