# How to detect templates in angular 2 after file separation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to  [learn how to start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) project in Angular 2 as so far got to second issue:
After following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders) I separated .ts from .js:

```
app: 'temp'  - in systemjs.config.js
"outDir": "temp"  -  in tsconfig.json
```

And of course I got to the issue, when If I'm creating files for template or style  (in app folder),they are not visible because there are not in the same folder as .js files.

For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'World'; }
```

I am receiving error: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load app.component.html`

And if I'm adding moduleId: module.id I get `Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load http://localhost:3000/temp/app.component.html`

I saw that it is possible to achieve if I add `.replace` to `module.id`, but this is not what I want (if possible, I'd wanted to not use `moduleId` at all). If possible, I'd like to not use `grunt` either (at this moment at least) (tried its `copy` functionality but it does not catch updates while `npm start` is running)

It seems super strange to me that by just wanting to separate .ts from compiled files gives so much trouble with anything that is not .ts files.

Is there a simple way to work with `.html` (or `.css/.scss` in case of style) in case if there are stored in different directories (not the same as where compiled .js are) ?

Comment: are you use webpack also?

Comment: I am super newbie speaking about angular and npm stuff, so... sorry, I might simply not understand what are we are talking about. What is webpack?

Comment: Webpack is a tool like Gulp .. try this in your Angular 2  component.. instead of templateUrl: './app.component.html', ..TRY template: require('./app.component.html')

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Webpack is a tool, like angularcli that helps you to build your application. Reload time using webpack incremental build is ~1s for small application, while angularcli takes too long. You should check it out, though for new person webpack configuration may be hard to grasp, but hey - I did it, that means that you can do it too :)

Comment: hm... is there any simple example of its configuration and usage?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`

try `template: require('./app.component.html')`

In Angular2 you don't need to deal with js files if you use Webpack. If you want to create a fast project to learn about it, try [AngularCLI](https://cli.angular.io/).

Comment: Does it need some additional configuration changes?