# Separating TypeScript and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cloned project from tour of heroes tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html.

And I want to separate .js files to another directory, because now I have .ts, .js and .js.map files all together in one directory.

I tried solve it following the answer from: [Separate Angular2 TypeScript files and JavaScript files into different folders, maybe 'dist‘](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684527/separate-angular2-typescript-files-and-javascript-files-into-different-folders) but after changes in systemjs.config.js and tsconfig.json I get an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.module
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.module
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.module as "./app/app.module" from http://localhost:3000/main.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.module as "./app/app.module" from http://localhost:3000/main.js
```

Comment: what IDE you use?

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: Most editors will put `.js` and `.js.map` 'folded' and hidden if they detect that typescript is used. Nowadays it's not often in a different directory as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
   "files.exclude": {
    "**/*.js.map": true,
    "**/*.js": {
        "when": "$(basename).ts"
    }
},
```

to your user settings

Comment: I have a problem.
My primary directory is app. And when I have all .ts files in this directory I don't see .js and .js.map files. But when I created a directory app/subdir/subdirectory and I put there .ts files I get .js files in directory app.